# Error in code blocks while building cocos2d-x "hello world" app

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, codeblocks

ERRORS:

- error: ‘glfwSetWindowMonitor’ was not declared in this scope
- recipe for target 'cocos2d/cocos/CMakeFiles/cocos2dInternal.dir/platform/desktop/CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp.o' failed
- recipe for target 'cocos2d/cocos/CMakeFiles/cocos2dInternal.dir/all' failed
- recipe for target 'all' failed
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should run ./frameworks/cocos2d-x/build/install-deps-linux.sh before building the project﻿

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431586/errors-while-building-class-cocos2d-x

Comment: pls i need asistance, im stuck on this

Comment: Yes. How can we help you ?   If you're having the same error showed at the top of this thread and you're running ubuntu, you should run the install-deps-linux.sh  before running the `cocos run -p linux` command

Comment: Actually i have problem with building custom class, here are the details 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431586/errors-while-building-class-cocos2d-x