# Errors while building class cocos2d-x

Tags: class, build, cocos2d-x

**I added class GraphicsScene.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"

class GraphicsScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(GraphicsScene);
};
```

Then

```
#include "GraphicsScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* GraphicsScene::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = GraphicsScene::create();
   scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

bool GraphicsScene::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
    sprite->setPosition(0, 0);

    this->addChild(sprite, 0);

    return true;
}
```

Then I added in AppDelegate instead of usual HelloWorld::createScene():

```
auto scene = GraphicsScene::createScene();
    // run
director->runWithScene(scene);
```

I added name of the class in Android.mk.

These are errors

[image]

What I m doing wrong? How to create class?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems good.

I guess you edited wrong Android.mk file. Please check what `Android.mk` file are you editing ?

The one in **proj.android** or the one in **proj.android-studio**?

When compiling using `--android-studio` tag, you are compiling the project inside **proj.android-studio**, not **proj.android**.

```
cocos compile -p android --android-studio
```

You're not using include guard in `GraphicsScene.h`. Use [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid the same header file being included multiple times.

**EDIT**

remove `static` keyword from `createScene` method definition inside GraphicsScene.cpp

```
static Scene* GraphicsScene::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = GraphicsScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

`Android.mk` of `proj.android-studio`

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GraphicsScene.cpp   --> Path is wrong for this file
```

so change this to `../../../Classes/GraphicsScene.cpp`

Comment: I added into both files firstly in proj.android and then in proj.android-studio just in case yet i get same errors.

Comment: Is it ok if you use prebuilt HelloWorld class ?

Comment: yes it works just fine, but at the moment i switch to my class it throws errors

Comment: - undefined reference to `GraphicsScene::createScene()'|
-ld returned 1 exit status|
- recipe for target 'bin/MyGame' failed
- recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all' failed|

Comment: if you want or can, ill send u my project so you can check whats wrong. Im stuck for two days on this problem.

Comment: ya sure, I'll happy to help you. you can share your project.

Comment: thank you very much, i uploaded project classes here

https://expirebox.com/download/d19631d3ca8c969330a566126451a946.html

Comment: please check updated Answer, I putted your source inside my Classes folder. remove `static` keyword from `createScene` method then added `GraphicsScene.cpp` inside `Android.mk` after that I run on AndroidStudio, it works.

Comment: i just did, it still happens same

Comment: Please share your `Android.mk` file ?

Comment: ok, 
https://expirebox.com/download/a411333288be179c960e7e6544283177.html

Comment: I don't think so problem is in your code or even in `Android.mk` so create a new fresh project, if that runs without any problem then go further with tiny steps. May be problem is in environment or platform.

Comment: You're using code blocks, why don't you try Android Studio or Xcode.

Comment: i did but since it had to be opened two android studios, one for building (or optionaly compile every time on terminal) and one for development also it needs android emulator or real device, i tried code blocks since it runs automatically on pc. But maybe i should try this on studio. Thank u very much for your effort